# how to declare a external package in package.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package.json

## situation:

1. I have three packages: A, B, and C.
2. All of those packages have a common dependency package: D.
3. And I have a project which depends on package A, B, C , and D.
4. package D is a big package (size > 500KB)
5. When I run **npm run build** in my project's root directory. Then the D package
   which is very big will be process 4 times, and make a very big bundle for my project!

## question:

Is there any way to make my project's bundle smaller ? I just want to process D package one time.

Comment: Did you try to run npm dedupe?

Comment: @SebastianSpeitel this may case more problems of "Can't resolve...."